# Show that if E is measurable set and f is continuous on E, then f(E) is measurable set

Tags: probability, analysis, measure-theory

Please tell me how to prove or disprove it !

Show that if E is measurable set and f is continuous on E, then f(E) is measurable set

Comment: Considering Lebesgue measure: Take the Cantor Staircase function $\phi$ and define $f(x)=\phi(x)+x$. The continuous function $f$ maps the measure-zero Cantor set onto a set $A$ of measure $1$. Consider a non-measurable subset of $A$ and a subset $B$ of the Cantor set with $f(B)=A$.

Comment: I am not convinced by David Mitra's answer since it is not clear (in the example) that $B$ exists. "Analytic sets" is a good thing to google. Dudley has Section 13.2 (Real Analysis and Probability) about a non-affirmative answer to your question, see http://books.google.de/books?id=7UuT7UZViN0C&lpg=PA493&ots=OOo_6ob0Jx&dq=continuous%20images%20of%20measurable%20sets%20are%20analytic&hl=de&pg=PA493#v=onepage&q=continuous%20images%20of%20measurable%20sets%20are%20analytic&f=false

Comment: @thomas I had a typo. Let $D$ be a non-measurable subset of $A=f(C)$, where $C$ is the Cantor set. One can certainly then find $B\subset C$ with $f(B)=D$. In fact, $f$ is one-to-one, so $B$ is just the unique set $f^{-1}(D)$.

Answer (score 1):

The [Cantor-Lebesgue function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor-Lebesgue_function) $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is a standard counterexample to this (with Lebesgue measure).  To show it is a counterexample, we need to find a set $S$ such that $S$ is measurable, yet $f(S)$ is not measurable.

Let $V$ be a [Vitali set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set), and let $v_0 \in V$ be the unique rational element of the vitali set.  Take $S = f^{-1}(V \setminus \{v_0\})$.

Recall one definition of the Cantor-Lebesgue function: if $x \in [0,1]$ has tertiary representation
$$
x = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{d_i}{3^i} \; \text{ where } d_i \in \{0,1,2\}
$$
then
$$
f(x) =
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
\displaystyle
\sum_{i=0}^{N-1} \frac{d_i/2}{2^i} + \frac{d_N}{2^N} & \text{if } d_N \text{ is the first digit equal to 1} \\
\displaystyle
\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{d_i/2}{2^i} & \text{if there is no digit equal to 1}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
(If $x$ has two tertiary representations, you can pick either one.)

- **$\boldsymbol{S}$ is measurable**

  Take any $a \in S$.  Then $f(a) = v + q$ for some $v \in V$, $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, with $v \ne v_0$.  Therefore $f(a)$ is irrational.  In particular, looking at the definition of $f$ above, $a$ must have no digit equal to $1$.  That is, $a \in \mathcal{C}$, where $\mathcal{C}$ is in the Cantor set.  So $S \subset \mathcal{C}$, with $\mu(C) = 0$, implying $S$ is measurable by completeness of Lebesuge measure.
- **$\boldsymbol{f(S)}$ is not measurable**

  $V$ is defined to be a subset of $[0,1]$.  Since $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 1$, by intermediate value theorem the image of $f$ contains $V$.  In particular, $f(S) = V \setminus \{v_0\}$.  This set is clearly not measurable since $V$ is not measurable and $\{v_0\}$ is measurable.

Comment: I am new to analysis, and I wonder what the *unique rational element of $V$* is, mentioned in this question. As far as I've learned so far, Vitali sets consist of irrationals only.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin Every Vitali set has one rational number in it. The definition of a Vitali set is that we define two real numbers to be "equivalent" if they differ by a rational number; so for example $\pi$ and $\pi + 3$ are equivalent. Then we take exactly one element from each equivalence class. Notice that every rational number is equivalent, so that means we pick exactly one rational number when we are constructing the Vitali set.